# Programmatically Control Tint of NavigationBarTitle swift ui

Tags: swiftui, navigation, titlebar

I have this problem where, upon fetching data from my servers, the `navigationBarTitle` above my `ScrollView` (and `ScrollViewReader`) does not recognize that it needs to automatically tint itself and so it appears awkwardly in the middle of my content. The reason why the content is appearing so close to the top of the screen is because I'm programmatically scrolling to the bottom `.onAppear` with my `ScrollViewReader`.

[image]

Note: "Feed" is the `.inline` title for this screen. Also, the date also awkwardly inserted in the middle of my hexagon view (also a date view, note the distinction).

After I navigate to another tab and return, Swift recognizes that it needs to automatically tint the `navigationBarTitle` and everything appears as it should.

[image]

Is there any way I can control when SwiftUI tints the `navigationBarTitle`? It should, of course, work by itself, but everything I've changed hasn't improved the situation. And it's not as though I can paste my code for you guys to debug--it's too integrated with live servers for that to be feasible.

However, if there's not a straightforward way to programmatically tint the `navigationBarTitle`, I can invest the time to try to recreate the problem with on a minimal example.

EDIT:

The problem also has to do with how I'm loading the my fetched data. The navigation title doesn't appear awkwardly in my content when I show my menu view after everything is loaded--it does when I show my menu view, then a blank screen until my feed loads.

Answer (score -1):

I was struggling with NavigationBar today too.
I ended up in reading and understanding the [Apple Documentation about Navigation Appearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar).
I have not the same problem as you, but my solution was to remove all changing lines of code which modify the appearance of UINavigationController. Then clean implement the section "Customize the Navigation Bar Appearance".
Probably you can try to do the same. Here is a [guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/cracking-the-navigation-bar-secrets-with-swiftui-30e9b019502c) which does it in SwiftUI.