# Add Back Button to UINavigationBar SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation, navigationbar

I had to customize my navigation bar for reasons outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934974/programmatically-control-tint-of-navigationbartitle-swift-ui) post, but SwiftUI is now not generating back buttons for me automatically. How can I add them?

See my sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

init() {
    
    let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    coloredAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
    coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = coloredAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
}
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLink(destination: Color.purple) {
                Text("Continue")
                    .navigationTitle("Nav Title 2")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }) {
                Text("Continue")
                    .navigationTitle("Nav Title 1")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code, back buttons are generated but in white color, as a consequence they are not visible in the navigation bar.

To display back buttons change:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
```

To:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(.accentColor)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I actually realized this a couple of days ago haha